# failed to load jvm.dll eclipse error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

i downloaded adt bundle from this site http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. but when i am trying to open eclipse i am getting this error. Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk 1.7.0_45\bin..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll" how to over come this??

my eclipse.ini file has this data

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.in32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product 
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: The eclipse.ini shows you have a 64 bit Eclipse - but you are using a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: @greg-449 how did you get that i am having a 32 bit jvm?

Comment: It is in `Program Files (x86)`, 64 bit code goes in `Program Files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure your os ,java and eclipse have the same bit i.e. 32 bit or 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall jdk which is in your system and install it again
make sure the setup file of jdk you have is campatible for yor os.
if you are not sure for this download it from here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Answer (score 0):

No need do anything simply install same BIT platform version of jdk and eclipse it's will works.
1. Install both either 32 bit or 64 bit